# Correct usage of itertools in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to expand the following list
`[(1, [('a', '12'), ('b', '64'), ('c', '36'), ('d', '48')]), (2, [('a', '13'), ('b', '26'), ('c', '39'), ('d', '52')])]`

to

`[(1,a,12),(1,b,24),(1,c,36),(1,d,48),(2,a,13),(2,b,26),(2,c,39),(2,d,52)]`

I used zip(itertools.cycle()) in python 3, but instead get a zip object reference. Is there any other way I can do it? This worked for python 2

Comment: zip (and map) in python3 returns an generator. use `list(zip(...))` should fix it

Comment: I would have just done `[(n,) + tup for n, tuples in thing for tup in tuples]`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner nitpick: neither `zip` nor `map` return a generator, although, they return iterators.

Comment: lst_source = [(1, [('a', '12'), ('b', '64'), ('c', '36'), ('d', '48')]), (2, [('a', '13'), ('b', '26'), ('c', '39'), ('d', '52')])]

lst_result =  [(val3[0],val[0],val[1]) for val3 in lst_source  for val in [ val2 for val1 in lst_source for val2 in val1[1]]]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I stand corrected - they produce iterators. and ranges are immutable sequences - gotta get that into my head one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `zip` object is iterable. Much like other APIs in Python 3, this one now returns an iterable object (like a generator) that *lazily* evaluates its input, rather than returning the entire result in a `list`.

In most cases, you can use the object in the same way as you did before.

If you need a list, simply call `list()` on the `zip` object:

```
result_list = list(zip(itertools.cycle(...)))
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. That worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the zip object is created correctly, you can either do `list(zip_object)` or `[*zip_object]` to get the list.